# Правда и кривда

Tags: этимология

Кривда (синоним слова "ложь") ранее употреблялось широко и было, если можно так выразиться, парным антонимом к слову "правда" (они похоже звучали, но означали противоположные понятия).
Как же так вышло, что слово "правда" в русском языке сохранилось, а "кривда" - слово этимологически понятное и, как мне кажется, более емкое, исчезло? И откуда взялось слово "ложь"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кривда - относительный неологизм, придуманный по модели "правды". 
Происхождение "правды" не совсем понятно, ясно что в основе - право, правильный. Поэтому прямой аналогии у правды-кривды с прямой-кривой нет. Это и заставляет думать, что "кривда" - куда более позднее изобретение. "Кривды" нет в других славянских, что еще более затрудняет осмысление пары правда-кривда.
Очень большой вопрос, как могли называть "неправду" до "кривды". Скорее всего "ложью" и называли. Это слово во всех славянских есть.

Появление же этого неологизма, как и обратное вытеснение, вполне может быть связано с противопоставлением "правильный-прямой" (стоячий) - "ложный" (лежачий). Когда это противопоставление перестало осознаваться (с утерей "ложный" связи с "лежачий") "ложь" вернула себе исходные позиции. Подчеркну, это всего лишь слабая гипотеза. На сколько-нибудь серьезное исследование я тут не претендую.

Comment: По-моему, прямая аналогия как раз очевидна, ибо а) у Фасмера для древнерусского "правый" указано в том числе и значение "прямой" и б) есть уже похожий пример, когда "кривой" становится "лживым" — это слово "лукавый", в основе которого значение "изогнутый" ("лук" — дуга, изгиб).

Comment: ***кривда*** [крывда] существует в украинском в значении "несправедливость", источник его появления в украинском мне неизвестен

Answer (score 3):

На счёт лжи можно найти вот такую информацию: Ближайшая этимология: лгу, также ложь, род. п. лжи (см.), укр. лга́ти, блр. iлга́ць, др.-русск., ст.-слав. лъгати, лъжѫ ψεύδεσθαι, болг. лъ́жа, сербохорв. ла̀гати, ла̏же̑м, словен. lǝgáti, lážem, чеш. lháti, lhu (lžu), слвц. lhаt᾽, польск. ɫgać, ɫżę, в.-луж. ɫhać, ɫžu, н.-луж. ɫgaś, ɫdžu.
Дальнейшая этимология: Родственно др.-лит. ɫúginaité "предательский, изменнический" (Шпехт, KZ 68, 36; Отрембский, LР 1, 138), гот. liugan "лгать", д.-в.-н. liogan; с другой ступенью чередования: гот. laugnjan "отрицать, отвергать", д.-в.-н. lugî "ложь", ирл. род. п. ед. ч. logaissi "mendacii", fol-lugaim "скрываю, утаиваю".

Вряд ли "ложь" подменила собой антоним "правды" "кривду". Скорее всего "кривду" подменила конструкция "неправда", а "ложь" является антонимом слова "истина". Благо корни у слова истина находятся в тех же языках, что и у слова "ложь": Происходит от др.-русск., ст.-слав. истина (греч. άλήθεια, ἀκρίβεια, ср.: укр. і́стина, болг. и́стина, сербохорв. и̏стина, словенск. ȋstina, чешск. jistinа «истина», др.-польск. iścina «истина, капитал, наличные деньги». От истый, далее от праслав. , от кот. в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. исто «капитал», укр. ïсти́й, íстний «истинный, настоящий», ст.-слав. истъ, истовъ «истинный, сущий», болг. ист «тот же самый», исто «также», сербохорв. и̏сти̑ «тот же самый», и̏сто̑ «точно так же», словенск. ȋsti «тот же самый», чешск. jistý «подлинный, верный, определенный, надежный», др.-польск. ist, isty.

Answer (score 2):

Выбранный ответ в корне не верный. Происхождение "правды" давно понятно и прекрасно известно! Изначальное значение "правый" от праславянского - это именно "прямой". В болгарском именно так и сохранилось. Если вы болгарскому таксисту скажите "направо", то он уверенно поедет прямо. А "направо" по-болгарски "надесную". Сравни "о десную Отца". "Десн" в праславянском "правый". Так же было поначалу и во всех славянских языках. Поэтому "правда" - это то, что "прямо", честно, в глаза, в лицо, нечто настоящее. Тут вопросов нет. "Кривой" - в некоторых славянских языках имеет значение "лживый", редко даже "левый", а в литовском и латышском от этого же корня "крв" - совершенно четко "левый".

Comment: Правильно.  Но  во  многих  культурах ( и  в  русской  в  том  числе )  правая  сторона  противопоставляется  левой  как  положительная.  То  есть  правая - хорошо,  левая  -  плохо.  Правая  -  справедливость,  левая -  несправедливость.  Это  я  о  сказочном  споре,  как  жить  лучше:  по  правде  или  по  кривде.

Answer (score 0):

Кривда - неологизм, который не прижился и сохранил оттенок просторечия (у меня лично это слово ассоциируется с бабушкой, журящей внука свежепридуманной остротой). Возможно, потому, что это изобретение не тянет на "меткость". Оно не выглядит прямой противоположностью правды (ложь употребляется именно в этом значении), по своей редкой форме словообразования претендуя на вызывающее противопоставление этому слову. По смыслу своего корня оно напоминает о слове "кривотолки" (домыслы, искажающие реальное положение вещей, но не связанные с прямым утверждением обратного), потому и несёт иной смысл, чем уже имеющеся "ложь".

Comment: Кроме и ранее «кривотолков» бытовали ещё: кривоверие, кривосудие, кривый — неправый, кривец — виновник, ответчик.

Answer (score 0):

Если  и  неологизм,  то  не  такой  уж  недавний - сказки  Афанасьева  и  белорусские  сказки  это  слово  знают.  Янко  Купала  этим  словом  пользуется,  как  общепонятным.  Правда,  я  думаю,  что  синонимом  этому  слову  у  Купалы,  да  и  в  русских  сказках,  является  не  ложь,  а  несправедливость,  неправедность  в  основах  социального  бытия.